# scrollTo: Getting button images to scrollTo divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navigation, scrollto

I've not found an answer really specific to my case, which I would imagine is common. I'm looking to add the scrollTo effect to my webpage using jquery (or javascript). I still don't know what is the easiest way granted I've not gotten anything to work. :(

I have a single vertical page. Navigation is on the bottom of each div wrapper. I'd like my button areas to scroll to the divs. As of now, I've styled the buttons to link to the Divs. That's perfect, except, I need to add the animation.

You can have a look at my test page here: [my site](http://www.hiimmike.com/test)

I've tried scrollTo, but each of my buttons links to a specific div. Not sure how to modify the plugin to work for me.

I think the next best solution is inserting javascript that animates all links in a window? Definitely don't know where to find that code or how to modify it for my case.

Thanks in advance everyone, and I look forward to a solution from what seems to be a very vibrant community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BTncy/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    var ele_href= $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + ele_href).offset().top},'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Kyle, I tried your method and it didn't work out for me. I'm keeping the code however and as I learn more Javascript and JQuery, I'll revert back to it. I thank you for your time and energy. Are you twitter? lol, Please, tell me where to send the starbucks card!

Comment: If you settle on your HTML, I will happily write some jQuery to accomplish your needs. Just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

(Note, from your example you have the javascript in the title attribute, not an onclick, not sure if that's intended)

This doesn't use a plugin, but you could do something as simple as the following using jQuery:

```
function scrollTo (element) {
    var target = $(element).offset();
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: target.top}, 'slow');
}
```

This allows you to just specify the selector to what you want to scroll to, so it could be as simple as:

```
<div id="more">
    <a onclick="scrollTo('#intro_2_container'); return false;" href="#into_2_container">
        <img src="images/more.png" border="0" />
    </a>
</div>
```

In my quick testing that seemed to work. (After I fixed the typo of the target element in the scrollTo call)

Comment: Your note, what exactly do you mean? Looks like my javascript is after my css (which should probably be linked rather than cluttering my html file). I've since updated the code with your edits but still nothing. Do I need to site the .js package from scrollTo?

Comment: Whoopsie daisy! I had a typo in there, misspelled the ID of the element to scrollTo, the onclick should be: scrollTo('#intro_2_container'); return false;

Comment: OK, I'll try once more to see what I get. Thanks for coming to my help!

Comment: HAHA!!! YES! It's working beautifully! You have no idea how much you've helped me. Thanks so much. Tell me where to send the starbucks card. Are you on twitter? lol. Thanks again. I haven't uploaded it just yet for you to see the changes. Working out a few last design details before I do.

Comment: Hey guys. One last thing... For some reason, firefox doesn't like my scrollto links (each button in the page links to a #link). Why is that? And do you have any tips on how I can fix it? It's a www.hiimmike.com if you need to check out my code.